# Allowing requests to specific url but block all others

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a VM instance running in the cloud.

I would like to allow requests to one endpoint in the application running there from all sources, while blocking all requests to an other endpoint if they are not from a specific IP.

e.g. domain.com/endpoint should be accessible by all IPs - domain.com should be accessible from one IP.

Currently i am blocking all requests to domain.com if you are not from a specific IP using the firewall feature.

Unfortunatly i do not not know much about this subject - so i am having trouble even searching for what i need, since i dont know the right terms, or what the google cloud product would be called.
I looked briefly at endpoints, but it seems that is for APIs - so i dont think that is what i need.

Does anyone know what product i need to use?

EDIT:
I am running adguard home, using docker - it is already serving dns over tls, and i wish to serve dns over https too.
Both the domain.com request and the domain.com/endpoint request is served by the same image. The issue is that both the UI and doh is served on the same port, and it is not possible for me to configure which port the UI uses, at least from inside the menues. it does not seem wise to me to expose a login interface to the entire internet.
It would not be a problem for me add other docker containers to handle this. But i would prefer that it stayed a google cloud configuration issue. Cloudflare is also an option for me. It is already configured for other parts of my domain.

Comment: You use the functionality provided by your web server software.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MichaelHampton - are there no other way? As i am running my service in docker, i would prefer to keep the configuration in the cloud console, like i am doing now with my firewall rules

Comment: Are example/com and example.com/endpoing going to the same container or they're two saparate containers ? Please provide more details about your setup (frontend, backend) for better troubleshooting.

Comment: @Wojtek_B - i have updated my question. Please have an other look when you have the time

Comment: I'm trying to understand what's your actual setup; correct me if I'm wrong: you're running some web application and AdGuard in the same docker image ? And they are both using the same port ? AdGuard by default uses port 3000...

Comment: I am running https://hub.docker.com/r/adguard/adguardhome/dockerfile. Port 3000 is only used for initial setup. After which port 80 and 443 serves the webui. However the doh is also served on port 443, at the endpoint domain.com/dns-query. Which causes my predicament. I do not want to expose the login served at domain.com to the internet, but I want to provide access to the doh service

Answer (score 0):

I deployed mentioned container and was able to set up private DNS.

At first setup promt you're asked for the administrator interface so you can either change it to `localhost` (but then you need to access this instance from inside network which is very cumbersome and complicated) or: make it available in all interfaces but change port from 80 to something else (its just unencrypted `http`). I haven't found a feature allowing you to server admin panel over HTTPS unless I missed something.

If you set up admin panel at some other port then you can easily create [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) allowing incoming connections from just one IP (or a range of IP's).

---------- UPDATE ---------

To block request for `/admin` you can use [Cloud Armor based on a URL and/or IP](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#allow_or_deny_traffic_for_a_request_uri_that_matches_a_regular_expression). You can block all the traffic going to admin panel with the exception of one (or a range) IP(s).

Comment: My apologies - i have been busy. If you configure the dns to serve doh and dot, you will be installing a certificate, which will enable the UI on port 443. With no way to change it.
At the same time, the doh will also be served on port 443, but at the /dns-query endpoint, while the dot will be served at 853.
I am currently just using dot on my lan and in my devices wifi settings. But i would also like to use doh in firefox and other places that support that

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the solution for you.

Comment: As far as i can see, this does not allow differentiating requests based on port - at least there is no mention of doing it in the documentation.

I need to allow access to these based on IP: domain.com:80, domain.com:443 while at the same time allowing access for all on domain.com:443/dns-query and domain.com:853

Comment: @Morten Toudahl - Were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Have you tried splitting your services so that domain.com and domain.com/endpoint are running on two hosts?